# CSS: Fade-in transition in input text?

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

Is there a way to write a CSS transition that would fade in an input text element while the user is typing?

Currently, text can fade in within a normal HTML text element because we can tell it to transition from 0 to 1 opacity; but input text doesn't exist before a user types it in.

So for example, if I type in my username, the letters that I type fade in, each one going from 0 to 1 opacity in .3 seconds.

I've tried using transition and animation, but want to keep it within CSS.

Comment: Doesn't sound especially user friendly, are you sure you want to inconvenience the user?

Answer (score 6):

A possible way to achieve a similar effect: create a partially transparent overlay using linear-gradient and gradually reveal as you type by moving the mask position.

```
 <div id='container'>
    <input type='text'></input>
    <div class='fader'></div>
 </div>

$("input").on("keydown", function(e) {
    var width = $("input").val().length + 1;
    $(".fader").css("left", (width * 8) + 3);
});


#container {
    position: relative;
    height: 25px;
    width: 400px;
}

input {
    width: 100%;
}

input, .fader {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0;
    font-family: monospace;
}

.fader {
    top: 2px;
    bottom: 4px;
    pointer-events: none;
    background: linear-gradient(90deg, transparent 0px, white, 15px, white 100%);
    transition: left 1s ease;
}
```

Here's what it looks like as a fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/go7trwzx/1/

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there is any way to do this with an HTML `input` element, and certainly not without Javascript. Any solution would require you to create individual elements for each letter, then apply transitions to each element individually.

If you'd like a visual of what that would look like, check out the "type" example and accompanying source code here:
http://codyhouse.co/demo/animated-headlines/index.html