# INPUT placeholder animation when typing

Tags: html, css, placeholder

I've been trying to found a way to imitate the following animation on placeholders when the user starts typing, just like in the following GIF:

[Placeholder animation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LVWjf.gif)

I know how to animate a fade-out of the animation as soon as the user focus on the input but I haven't found anything yet about how to do this animation just when the user starts typing

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31281280/css-fade-in-transition-in-input-text is this what you are looking for? look at the JS fiddle on that page

Comment: can you share what you have tried so far?

Comment: check articles Float Labels with CSS http://mds.is/float-label-pattern/ & https://css-tricks.com/float-labels-css/

Answer (score 5):

> Hello below is the solution as you want the animation in placeholder

```css
input[type="text"] {
    font: 15px/24px "Lato", Arial, sans-serif;
    color: #333;
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
}
.effect-16, .effect-17, .effect-18 {
    border: 0;
    padding: 4px 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    background-color: transparent;
}
.effect-16 ~ label {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    top: 9px;
    color: #aaa;
    transition: 0.3s;
    z-index: -1;
    letter-spacing: 0.5px;
}
.effect-16 ~ .focus-border {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 0;
    height: 2px;
    background-color: #3399FF;
    transition: 0.4s;
}
.effect-16:focus ~ .focus-border, .has-content.effect-16 ~ .focus-border {
    width: 100%;
    transition: 0.4s;
}
.effect-16 ~ .focus-border {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 0;
    height: 2px;
    background-color: #3399FF;
    transition: 0.4s;
    
}
input:focus {
  outline: 0;
}
.effect-16:focus ~ label, .has-content.effect-16 ~ label {
    top: -16px;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #3399FF;
    transition: 0.3s;
}
.input-box {padding:50px 0px;}
.col-3 {
    float: left;
    width: 27.33%;
    margin: 40px 3%;
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<section class="input-box">
  <div class="container">
  
  
        <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-3 input-effect">
         <input class="effect-16" type="text" placeholder="">
            <label>First Name</label>
            <span class="focus-border"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-3 input-effect">
         <input class="effect-16" type="text" placeholder="">
            <label>Last Name</label>
            <span class="focus-border"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-3 input-effect">
         <input class="effect-16" type="text" placeholder="">
            <label>Address</label>
            <span class="focus-border"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-3 input-effect">
         <input class="effect-16" type="text" placeholder="">
            <label>Mobile</label>
            <span class="focus-border"></span>
        </div>
        </div>
</div>
        </section>
```